# How can you run Skyrim in borderless window mode?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

I've noticed Skyrim has some issues when minimizing. This is a real pain when playing on multiple monitors and you attempt to find something on the other monitor. Is there anyway to enable borderless window mode in Skyrim?

Comment: While this does not directly answer your question, I've found a way to alt-tab out of the game and back in successfully every time. After alt tabbing out, click back to bring up the game and generally you get a black screen. Hit alt+tab again to bring up the horizontal list. While that list is still up, click back in the skyrim window and everything will be fully functional again.

Comment: Cool, my strategy was spam click the icon in the window's taskbar. About the third click it recovers.

Comment: @Andy Alt-tabbing is noted in the Skyrim readme as being potentially unstable on some systems, and I can confirm that mine doesn't like it at all! :(

Comment: @AndyPerfect, yep, this has previously worked well for me. After I installed ENB, this has ceased to work, and any attempt at Alt+Tabbing back seems to just freeze the game. I guess that's something I just have to live with, I've become addicted to ENB graphics.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can't by default, but there is a mod to do this. Try it out [here](http://www.skyrimnexus.com/downloads/file.php?id=4).

Comment: This is an amazingly promising mod. Thank you for showing me this. +1

Answer (score 5):

#### [OneTweak](http://www.nexusmods.com/skyrim/mods/40706/?)

The Simple Borderless Window mod (suggested in [another answer](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/36133/4797)) has been set to 'hidden' by its author. In its page, the author suggests the [**OneTweak**](http://www.nexusmods.com/skyrim/mods/40706/?) mod instead, which allows borderless window mode. It also includes other Skyrim fixes: such as Alt+Tab double cursor fix, dynamic process priority (give Skyrim more CPU priority for better performance), RaceMenu Precache killer (prevents crashing). Another alternative is the [**Fake Fullscreen**](http://www.nexusmods.com/skyrim/mods/41784/?) mod, which also allows borderless window mode.

Answer (score 0):

You can get my application that works with almost any game and is automatic or hotkeyed. You can also check my small tutorial example script (download) to prepare you own little script.
Application:

Script:

Answer (score 0):

My recommendation would be to install the latest enbseries, since it also comes with a usefull patch, and you can turn off the graphical modification and just use the patches (which prevent memory overflow) and the borderless fullscreen mode.